# Accumulative count in Power BI

Tags: charts, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am new to Power BI

I am trying to build stacked line chart, by that i mean for the first day in the graph will be 1 the next date will be 2 then 3

My query looks like this

```
ID      DateTime
A847    17-Feb-18
G927    02-Mar-18
T256    13-Mar-18
K123    30-Mar-18
K973    09-Apr-18
B611    02-May-18
L920    28-May-18
W277    12-Jun-18
J737    25-Jun-18
G101    10-Jul-18
```

The graph should look like this

[image]

Comment: Being that you aren't "new" to SO I find it strange that you don't accept either answer. These solutions require time on our part and the fact that you just ghost responses is quite rude.

Comment: @StelioK coz i was in leave and i just came back..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it will be more efficient, but you can try this version:

```
Count Cum = COUNTX(FILTER(Table, Table[Date] <= EARLIER(Table[Date])), 1)
```

Or simply

```
Count Cum = COUNTROWS(FILTER(Table, Table[Date] <= EARLIER(Table[Date])))
```

Comment: That seems strange that Calculate would be so expensive, I've literally never run into memory issues in power bi and I've dealt with models with tables in excess of 20 million rows. Have you ever run into something like this before?

Comment: It shouldn't be that expensive unless something is off with your relationship diagram and it is trying to count a massive cross-join or something like that.

Comment: Yea, pretty strange indeed.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by creating a calculated column like so:

```
Cum Count = CALCULATE(
            COUNTROWS(Table)
            , FILTER( Table
              , Table[date] < EARLIER(Table[date]))
)
```

I tested this and it works fine just ensure that your dates are in ascending order.

Comment: After few minutes waiting for the calculated column to finish I got this message "There's not enough memory to complete this operation" I only have 65k records

Comment: Wow sounds like you have some hardware limitations, I'll see if I can find another way of calculating.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you try `CALCULATE(COUNT(Table[ID]), FILTER( Table, Table[date] <= EARLIER(Table[date]))`